# Adding nologin ftp users

Tags: linux, unix, ftp

I have set up an FTP account on a linux machine with vsftpd for a single user.

Now, how would I add a new user with parameters:

- base_folder
- username
- password

Answer (score 1):

The "right" way is to use `PAM` to create virtual users just for vsftpd.  [This site](http://howto.gumph.org/content/setup-virtual-users-and-directories-in-vsftpd/) has a basic description using a separate `passwd` file for vsftpd, but with enough work you can make PAM use a database as well.  Since the accounts in a separate passwd file, they can't log in to the computer.  Since it uses a completely separate passwd file, your existing user will have to be copied into that file in order to be able to use FTP

PAM can also [allow both the virtual users and the real users to log in](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/how-to-enable-both-virtual-and-local-vsftpd-logins-with-pam-365860/) to vsftp.  Then you won't have to copy your real users into the vsftp virtual user passwd file.